# Option Group Selection - Search Criteria Form

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

I have created a search criteria form that allows the user to search through fields for certain data, and It works flawlessly.

Now, I've created a Option Group that has "Customer" - "Supplier" and "Other".

I want one of these to be selecable, and searched for. I figured if I create a field that has "S" for Supplier, "C" for Customer and "O" for Other, and then depending on whatever they select - The records listed with this Field come up, nothing more.

I can provide any information regarding the search criteria if needed!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes? The question is implied, but I suppose I can state it outright if that is needed. I need to make my OptionGroup only show certain records (Customer,Supplier,Other) when they are selected - How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I've reverted from doing an option group that allows the user to select a  radio button, and gone with just making a simple drop down selection with a little VBA search criteria. Thanks for taking the time to inquiry!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a field in your table that allow to discrimine between groups. That field (eg Group) can have 0,1,2 values.
Assign for each option in the option group the corresponding value of 0-Customers, 1-Suppliers, 2-Others
the search criteria would be like this

```
sql = "select * from tableName where group = " & OptionGroup
```

Comment: Cool, where abouts would I code this in? Before Update in the OptionGroup properties?

Comment: Best, in AfterUpdate. In BeforeUpdate the option group value is provissional. In AfterUpdate is confirmed. If you have more than 1 criteria, I usually write the filtering code in a 'Search' button